# Is there a jquery plugin to implement customized avatar?

Tags: jquery

Should pop up many images and let the user choose one as his avatar.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery plugins - layouts page](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/51) features a whole load of image galleries, carousels, lightboxes, etc. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something you could make quickly:

```
<a href="#" class="show-thumbnails">Show Thumbnails</a>
<div id="thumbnails" style="display:none;">
  <img src="puppies.jpg" /> 
  <img src="unicorns.jpg" />
  <img src="bunnies.jpg" />
</div>
<input type="text" name="userThumbnail" />
```

--

```
$(".show-thumbnails").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#thumbnails").fadeIn();
});

$("#thumbnails img").click(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  $(":input[name='userThumbnail']").val(src);
});
```